# Determine vectors that are in the solution space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am doing a past exam question that gives a $4 \times 6$ matrix $A$ along with four $6 \times 1$ vectors and asks you to determine which vectors are in the solution space of $A$.

$$
A=\pmatrix{-1&2&3&-3&6&7\\1&-1&-2&2&-5&-6\\-1&1&2&-1&2&4\\-2&2&4&-2&4&8}.
$$

I have already calculated the solution space of $A$ but cannot find any of the $4$ vectors in the solution space. Could somebody tell me what to do for this question?

Comment: May be you can multiply $A$ by each vector  $Av$, so if you get zero then your vector $v$ is in the solution space .

Comment: Solution space of which equation?

Answer (score -2):

Let the vector be $\mathbf x$, using Matlab to test whether $\mathbf{Ax=0}$. If the product is $\mathbf0$, then we say that the vector is in the solution space.

Comment: Hope you did well in the Matlab test